# c++ move semantics does not perform move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Idea is to use move semantics to avoid unnecessary copying.
Given the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>



class Address {
private:
    const std::string m_street;
    const std::string m_city;
    const int m_suite;

public:
    Address(const std::string &street, const std::string &city, int suite) : m_street {std::move(street)},
                                                                            m_city {std::move(city)},
                                                                            m_suite {suite}
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Address &address)
    {
        out << "Address: (street: " << address.m_street << ", city: " << address.m_city << ", suite: " << address.m_suite << ")\n";

        return out;
    }

    Address(const Address &other) = delete;

    Address& operator=(const Address &other) = delete;

    Address(Address &&other) : m_street {std::move(other.m_street)},
                               m_city {std::move(other.m_city)},
                               m_suite {std::move(other.m_suite)}
    {
    }
};


class Contact {
    const std::string m_name;
    const Address m_address;

public:
    Contact(const std::string &name, Address &address) : m_name {std::move(name)},
                                                        m_address {std::move(address)}
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Contact &contact)
    {
        out << "Contact: " << contact.m_name << "\n" << contact.m_address << "\n";

        return out;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Address address1 {"123 East Dr", "London", 123};
    Contact john {"John Doe", address1};

    std::cout << john;
    std::cout << address1;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the prinout of:

```
Contact: John Doe
Address: (street: 123 East Dr, city: London, suite: 123)

Address: (street: 123 East Dr, city: London, suite: 123)
```

Why isn't the content of the address1 variable moved? Shouldn't the printout be

```
Address: (street: , city: , suite: <whatever>)
```

Also, why is there a restriction for a post that is mostly code? Everything is given in the code. I was interested in move semantics so I created address1 variable that will hold some address. I used the same variable to initialize an object of type Contact (using the move semantics), but the move semantics is not performed and the address1 variable still holds the same values.

Comment: `Why isn't the content of the address1 variable moved?` Why would it? Its not a rvalue.

Comment: but it is passed as a reference to the Contact constructor, and then move is performed to make a rvalue out of it?

Comment: Better to have `Contact(const std::string &name, Address&& address)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data member `m_street` and `m_city` are declared as `const`; then in the member initializer list of move constructor of `Address` like `m_street {std::move(other.m_street)}`, the copy constructor (but not move constructor) of `std::string` is used.

You might want to remove the `const` qualifier, then you'll get

```
Contact: John Doe
Address: (street: 123 East Dr, city: London, suite: 123)

Address: (street: , city: , suite: 123)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SSxqZc9N7UB1goEy)

BTW: For built-in types like `int`, the effect of move is same as copy. That's why the value of `suite` is still `123`.

BTW2: For the move constructor of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string),

> Move constructor. Constructs the string with the contents of `other` using move semantics. `other` is left in valid, but unspecified state.

After move operation the moved object doesn't guarantee to be modified to empty.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that in general the moved from object can be in any state, not getting modified is uncommon but not necessarily wrong

Comment: @idclev463035818 Added. This is true for `std::string` too.